# Need to add substring() column after destination oledb table

Tags: sql, ssis

I simple created a SSIS dataflow and I got the OLEDB Destination table but I want to add one more column on my final table but it seems like I am not able to do it. any suggestion.

```
SELECT [NAME]
,[ID]
,[TYPE]
,[CLASS]
,[START_DATE]
,[END_DATE]
,[LINE1]
,substring([LINE1],1,5) c
,[LINE2]
,[LINE3]
,[LINE4]
,[CITY]
,[STATE]
,[POSTAL_ZIP]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Add one more column? this column not created in Destination Table? if already created then just select out and map them, if not, you better create it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived column *after* your merge join task to add an additional column based on a transformation or replication on an existing column or based on an existing variable or parameter.

[image]

You can use the derived column to transform your existing LINE1 column using the SSIS scripting language:

```
SUBSTRING([LINE1],1,5)
```

[image: d column in]

Comment: I totally forgot this part, Thanks for your help.